# Any way to echo the value of a logical comparison in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, boolean

for example can how can I properly write,

```
$a = 'cat-dog';
echo ((strpos($a, '-') !== false));
// and get true on screen.
```

Without having to use a separate variable to store the value.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the function `var_dump();` instead of `echo`. Have a look at the [manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

For example:

```
$a = 'cat-dog';
var_dump(strpos($a, '-') !== false);
//Would output: bool(true)
```

Comment: Thanks!I know this is a new question, but would it also be possible to store it in a new variable? like so `$myVariable = (strpos($a, '-') !== false);` this doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @Mohammad what do you want to save? a boolean variable or a string?

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ternary operator:

```
echo ((strpos($a, '-') !== false) ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 'cat-dog';
echo (strpos($a, '-') !== false) 
   ? "true" 
   : "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just cast the result to string with (string)($AnyResult)?

Answer (score 1):

instead of stacking operators and using ternary operator you have also possibility to write readable and maintainable code

```
$a = 'cat-dog';
$pos = strpos($a, '-');
if ($pos !== false) {
  echo "TRUE";
}
```

I see no rocket science in it though. just regular PHP operators, donno what made it trouble for you.